# Group by count based on condition on what to count Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So let's say I have a df that looks like this:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                       'Data2' : [100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100],
                       'Data3' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
                       'State' : ['On', 'On', 'Off', 'Off', 'On', 'On']})
```

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | State |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| A     |   100 |     1 | On    |
| A     |   100 |     2 | On    |
| A     |   200 |     3 | Off   |
| B     |   100 |     1 | Off   |
| B     |   100 |     1 | On    |
| B     |   100 |     1 | On    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to do a groupby of Data1, Data2 then do a nunique count on Data3, but only count the one's with State value is 'On'.

So my result would look like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | State | Count |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| A     |   100 |     1 | On    |     2 |
| A     |   100 |     2 | On    |     2 |
| A     |   200 |     3 | Off   |     0 |
| B     |   100 |     1 | Off   |     1 |
| B     |   100 |     1 | On    |     1 |
| B     |   100 |     1 | On    |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Here's what I have that I know is wrong since it groups by State, but I am not sure how to make it group by only Data1 and Data2 while only doing counts with State = 'On' close.

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Data1', 'Data2', 'State'])['Data3'].transform('nunique')
```

Any and all help is apprecaited!

Comment: df[df['State'] == 'On'].groupby . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do a boolean mask with `groupby.nunique` followed by left merge :

```
cols = ['Data1','Data2']
m = df[df['State'].eq("On")].groupby(cols)['Data3'].nunique()
out = (df.merge(m,left_on=cols,right_index=True,how='left',suffixes=('','_counts'))
       .fillna({"Data3_counts":0}))
```

---

```
print(out)

  Data1  Data2  Data3 State  Data3_counts
0     A    100      1    On           2.0
1     A    100      2    On           2.0
2     A    200      3   Off           0.0
3     B    100      1   Off           1.0
4     B    100      1    On           1.0
5     B    100      1    On           1.0
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `reindex`

```
df['Count'] = df[df['State'].eq('On')].groupby(['Data1','Data2'])['Data3'].nunique().reindex(df.Data3).values
```

Comment: doesn't this count all of them? I only want to count on unique values for Data3?

Comment: @mike_gundy123 then let us try do agg function then reindex back

Comment: I seem to be getting an error at the re-indexing part
Argument 'tuples' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Categorical)